# PayPal - several API type "can it be done questions"

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have an app that is both Web and Mobile. I know what I am trying to do is a bit messy but I was hoping someone could help guide me through the options please. I have done some reading and check replies on Stackoverflow but I'm am getting confused.

The main criteria here is I do not want to have the users log in to PayPal every time, approve a transaction every time. So I guess part of the solution is to have them set up an Agreement to pay ?

I have a Business account.

a) 
is it possible to transfer funds from a users bank account they have with paypal, to some other paypal account. In other words make a payment from their bank account to a specified paypal account they do not own (namely some merchant)

b)
is it possible to transfer funds from one paypal account to another. Lets say mine to someone else's.

c) 
is it possible to transfer funds from one paypal account to another. Lets say someone else's to mine.

d)
is it possible to transfer funds from my paypal account to someone else's bank account.

e)
I guess PayPal IPN could be used for instant notification ?

All of the above needs to be done in the background without user involvement apart from them  entering the amount, and say yes proceed. No passwords or bank account details to be entered etc.

I would preferably like to do the above on a web server rather than on a mobile device. So within server-side code.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do some of what you are asking using a [Billing Agreement](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns/#id094UM0C03Y4). In a BA, you agree that I can charge your Paypal account without a further login. It's a one-time setup.

You can use the MassPay API call to pay anyone. All you need is their email address. There is a fee to you to do this, tho.

You can make third party calls (where I make calls on your behalf) so it's theoretically possible for me to issue a MassPay on your behalf.

You cannot send money to a bank account (i.e. ACH-style). You can send it to their paypal and they can log in and move it from there.

All transactions will send an IPN if you have one specified.

Hope that helps

Comment: Appreciate the feedback Machavity. I did forget to include this question if you wouldn't mind commenting if you can,
...can I pass a credit card payment, namely credit card number, name, CSV, to PayPal via an API rather than have a person manually entering the details every time ?
By this I mean the info is stored elsewhere and all they need to do is enter a password for example to 'authorize' the payment. cheers

Comment: Yes, you can do this pretty easily. It's called a Reference Transaction and all you need is the original transaction ID (original transaction could be something as simple as a $1 authorization). https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoReferenceTransaction_API_Operation_NVP/
One caveat is that you will have to turn off CVV2 checks for this. PCI says Paypal can't store it and neither can you. Disabling your CVV2 check will let you run this without any problems.